# create loop using values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I have an array D of variable length,

I want to create a loop that performs a sum based on the value of D corresponding to the number of times looped

i.e. the 5th run through the loop would use the 5th value in my array.

My code is:

```
period = 63 # can be edited to an input() command for variable periods.
Mrgn_dec = .10 # decimal value of 10%, can be manipulated to produce a 10% increase/decrease
rtn_annual = np.arange(0.00,0.15,0.05) # creates an array ??? not sure if helpful
sig_annual = np.arange(0.01,0.31,0.01) #use .31 as python doesnt include the upper range value.


#functions for variables of daily return and risk.
rtn_daily = (1/252)*rtn_annual
sig_daily = (1/(np.sqrt(252)))*sig_annual
D=np.random.normal(size=period) # unsure of range to use for standard distribution

for i in range(period):
    r=(rtn_daily+sig_daily*D)
```

I'm trying to make it so my for loop is multiplied by the value for D of each step.

So D has a random value for every value of period, where period represents a day.

So for the 8th day I want the loop value for r to be multiplied by the 8th value in my array, is there a way to select the specific value or not?

Does the numpy.cumprod command offer any help, I'm not sure how it works but it has been suggested to help the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can select element in an iterative object (such as D in your code) simply by choosing its index. Such as:

```
for i in range(period):
    print D[i]
```

But in your code, rtn_daily and sig_daily are not in the same shape, I assume that you want to add sig_daily multiply by D[i] in each position of rtn. so try this:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

period = 63 # can be edited to an input() command for variable periods.
Mrgn_dec = .10 # decimal value of 10%, can be manipulated to produce a 10% increase/decrease
rtn_annual = np.repeat(np.arange(0.00,0.15,0.05), 31) # creates an array ??? not sure if helpful
sig_annual = np.repeat(np.arange(0.01,0.31,0.01), 3) #use .31 as python doesnt include the upper range value.


#functions for variables of daily return and risk.
rtn_daily = (float(1)/252)*rtn_annual
sig_daily = (1/(np.sqrt(252)))*sig_annual
D=np.random.normal(size=period) # unsure of range to use for standard distribution
print D
for i in range(period):
    r=(rtn_daily[i]+sig_daily[i]*D[i])
    print r
```

Last of all, if you are using python2,  the division method is for integer, so that means 1/252 will give you zero as result.

```
a = 1/252 >-- 0
```

to solve this you may try to make it float:

```
rtn_daily = (float(1)/252)*rtn_annual
```

Comment: Division is integer for py2. It certainly isn't in py3.

Comment: Sorry I assume he uses py2, but that is not the real problem.

Comment: no it's not, but you did start of your answer with that, and spent enough time discussing it to make me think you found it to be significant.

Comment: Ok, with a few additions to make it fit with my code this seems to have fixed the problem I was having. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem buddy! Happy to help!

Answer (score -1):

<s>Right now, D is just a scalar.</s>

I'd suggest reading https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html to learn about the parameters.

If you change it to:

```
D=np.random.normal(mean,stdev,period)
```

you will get a **1D array** with *period* number of samples, where mean and stdev are your mean and standard deviation of the distribution. Then you change the loop to:

```
for i in range(period):
    r=(rtn_daily+sig_daily*D[i])
```

EDIT: I don't know what I was thinking when I read the code the first time. It was a horribly bad read on my part.

Looking back at the code, a few things need to happen to make it work.

First:

```
rtn_annual = np.arange(0.00,0.15,0.05)
sig_annual = np.arange(0.01,0.31,0.01)
```

These two lines need to be fixed so that the dimensions of the resulting matricies are the same.

Then:

```
rtn_daily = (1/252)*rtn_annual
```

Needs to be changed so it doesn't zero everything out -- either change 1 to 1.0 or float(1)

Finally:

```
r=(rtn_daily+sig_daily*D)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
r=(rtn_daily+sig_daily*D[i])
```

I'm not really sure of the intent of the original code, but it appears as though the loop is unnecessary and you could just change the loop to:

```
r=(rtn_daily+sig_daily*D[day])
```

where day is the day you're trying to isolate.

Comment: My assumption is that there is more processing in that loop than is displayed.

Comment: OP is using the keyword `size`. The other parameters have sensible defaults. It is you who did not understand the docs.

Comment: is D not an array? when i used print(type(D)) it returns "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"

Comment: Mad Physicist is right, I missed the size= portion of the code when I read through it. D would be an array, which would mean the loop would be the same, D[i] would be the ith part of the array. Rereading the question, I'm also not sure why the loop is needed if you're just calculating r for one specific day.

Comment: i have a value that changes daily for 60 days in a row, but the change can be an increase or decrease in random range, i figured a loop would make it easier to calculate the change for each day. Although i may have poorly explained my issue. Thanks for the help though, i included a comment to remind myself to check for scalar/ndarray